# Скругление углов полигона

Tags: алгоритм, yandex-maps-api, геометрия

На карте отрисован полигон. Требуется углы этого полигона закруглить. Есть ли у Яндекс.Карт какая-нибудь функция, упрощающая данную задачу?

Ну ли подскажите алгоритм для закругления углов полигона.

Answer (score 0):

У Яндекс.Карт только прямоугольники умеют скруглять углы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/rectangle
Остальные геометрии не умеют.